# TypeError when using substring function in Python 3

Tags: python, csv, pandas, substring

I wrote a function to open a csv, find max of data in a column & then substring to take only last 4 digits. It worked very well for almost 2 hours. But suddenly failing with the error `TypeError: unorderable types: float() > str()` Relevant code is:

```
import pandas

mycsvfile = 'filepath'
df = pandas.read_csv(mycsvfile, sep=",", usecols=['ColumnName'])
start_num=int(max(df['ColumnName'])[-4:])+1
```

Values in the column are of the format XXXX11XX1111 where X's are alphabets & 1's are numerals. I want to extract only last four digits of this field.

What baffles me is that it was working perfectly fine for more than 1000 records & suddenly started failing for no reason. I even deleted records & started a fresh, still it fails.

Comment: The `TypeError` is caused by the `max(df['ColumnName'])` expression, not the slice. Presumably your column contains floating point values.

Comment: Oops! I had missed seeing one empty cell in a list of few thousands. Found now. Replaced with actual value & its fine now. Thank you @MartijnPieters

Comment: Close as **"a problem that can no longer be reproduced"** ? Or maybe you should post your own self-accepted answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Empty cell in the column caused that issue. Filling it with appropriate value resolved the issue.